# update alertdialogs without updating app

Tags: android, client-server, push-notification

I have searched heavily for an answer but can't find how to do this; I want to be able to send a new `AlertDialog` to users when the app starts, but only when I have a new message (not every time the app starts) without running an update every time.  For now I am using `SharedPreferences` and setting a Boolean checking to see if the user has viewed the message on each run but this is not the correct approach because an update is required each time I want to show a new message.  Checking for the app version number will not help since the new messages won't be based on app updates.  If someone could please steer me in the right direction I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There exists no magic way to figure out if the user should see a message - you need a piece of info to determine if there is a message to view. I have not messed around with any of this, but I have seen enough stackoverflow posts to determine that you need some sort of push message service.
There are a few I can think of:

- [Google Cloud Messaging](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html)
- [Urban Airship](http://urbanairship.com/products/push-messaging)

There is also [Amazon](http://www.androidauthority.com/kindle-fire-push-messaging-139723/) doing something similar, but it's not finalized yet.
So I suggest reading up on each implementation, seeing what costs you need to make, and trying things out.

There's also a very limited quick and dirty way I can think of. It involves making a webpage with the message you want your app to display and when the app starts, it scrapes your web page for data, compares what it currently has with what it scraped, then based on that shows a dialog.

Obviously all these methods require an internet connection.

Happy coding!

Comment: Thank you. I like your last suggestion, since making a web page will be easy for me. I've never scraped a web page but I know the concept. Guess I need to save the page's content in a SharedPreference then compare the string on app start? This should be easy unless you have a better suggestion.

Comment: Yeah, SharedPreferences would be an easy way to handle it. I don't see a need for a database since you're only storing one message.

Comment: No problem, it made me think of implementing something like this too.

Comment: I uploaded an XML file to my server and I will just parse that using DOMParser to get a string value, then check that string against a `SharedPreferences` value when the app loads. Will be easy to add a new message to the XML file and the app will display the AlertDialog when the string changes. Thanks for guiding me in the right direction.